# Compare attachments of Opportunities

Tags: apex

How I can compare attachments of 2 Opportunities whether they are similar or different using Apex?

for example: 
if Oppy1 has 2 attachments as 1.txt, 2.txt & 3.txt
and if Oppy2 has 3 attachments as 1.txt & 2.txt
then I will get the result as 3.txt added to Oppy1, which is missing in Oppy2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will create a map where each key is the Opportunity id and each value is the ordered List of Attachment names for that Opportunity. This assumes you only care about name differences; if you care about more you can query other Attachment fields too but querying the Attachment.Body will run you up against the Apex heap size limit if the Attachments are large.

```
Id oppy1Id = ...;
Id oppy2Id = ...;
Set<Id> oppyIds = new Set<Id>{oppy1Id, oppy2Id};

Map<Id, List<String>> m = new Map<Id, List<String>>();
for (Id oppyId : oppyIds) {
    m.put(oppyId, new List<String>());
}

for (Attachment a : [
        select Name, ParentId
        from Attachment
        where ParentId in :oppyIds
        order by Name
        ]) {
    m.get(a.ParentId).add(a.Name);
}

List<String> oppy1Names = m.get(oppy1Id);
List<String> oppy2Names = m.get(oppy2Id);
// Use List (and Set) logic to work out what is different
```